# Laravel - Basic route 404

Tags: php, laravel

I am refreshing my Laravel basics and have run into an issue straight away.

I am using a Bitnami WAMP stack and have a Laravel project setup and working. The first change I have made is to add another route to the /routes/web.php file like this...

```
Route::get('/hello', function () {
    return 'Hello world';
});
```

But when I go to my url www.example.com/hello I get a 404

Artisan shows the route...

```
| GET|HEAD | hello    |      | Closure | web
```

Anyone any pointers on troubleshooting? Could it be my Bitnami configuration at fault?

Comment: What about `artisan route:list`?

Comment: is your project folder name has upper case letters??

Comment: Have updated the original post, route:list does seem to show the route correctly

Comment: Do any other routes (eg `/`) work? Is the docroot correctly set up at `/public`, etc?

Comment: The standard / route works correctly, just nothing else. I am starting to think this is related to mod_rewrite somehow. It is enabled

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the cache, try:

```
php artisan route: clear
```

Server-side caching is also possible.

Just try to install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar there you can see how it works out the route.

Still look at rewrite_module on apache https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#web-server-configuration

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work this one out in the end. I needed to add the following to my Apache httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wamp/apache2/htdocs/myapp/public"
    ServerName siteagent.test
    <Directory "C:/Bitnami/wamp/apache2/htdocs/myapp/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```